# jQuery datepicker not showing binded date

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery datepicker

```
$(".monthPickerStart").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'MM yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('d M,yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
      }
});

$(".monthPickerStart").focus(function () 
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
            my: "center top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: $(this)
      });
});
```

aspx page code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" class="monthPickerStart" Text='<%# Eval(Date", "{0:MMM/dd/yyyy}") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Problem:
If their is already a date in this text box and when I try to open datepicker, then it opens the current date, rather than opening the date which is present inside that textbox. for example date inside textbox = 5/13/2019, then when i try to open datepicker then it opens current date instead of 5/13/2019

Comment: Have you properly set the date format? Because if you haven't `5/13/2019` is not a valid date with the default settings

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow

Comment: any one please explain in the above code what is the use of "of: $(this)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate you have to set the date format properly
Since you are using `dateFormat: 'MM yy'` to initialize the Datepicker,
The Input field text value should contain the default value as `May 2019`
All the date formats supported are mentioned in the link above

Comment: Thanks Amogh, When I gave input format properly, it started working

Comment: You are Welcome :)